# Multilevel Imputation: glmer and HMI

Tags: r, imputation

Trying to fit a two-level imputation model with HMI (hierch. multiple imputation)...

The model I'm using is this (I want random intercept ONLY):

```
glmer(pica_yn ~ 1 + visit_c+visit_c2 + geo_child + hhloc  + diar_c + hemo_c + (1|pid))
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error in buildZ(rmodel.terms[r], data = data, nginverse =
>   names(ginverse)): object id not found

It seems as though HMI prefers the specified formula also has a random slope.

Has anyone fit a multilevel imputation model for a *BINARY* response?

Here is an example you can run that will get the same error:

`data("sleepstudy", package="lme4")
sleepstudy[sample(1:nrow(sleepstudy), size = 20), "Reaction"] <- NA
sleep_formula<-Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject)
hmi_imp <- hmi(data = sleepstudy, model_formula = sleep_formula, M = 5, maxit = 1)`

Comment: Note that this is with the package "hmi" in R.

Comment: can you provide a reproducibleexample (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? This might include code to generate a small fictitious data set resembling your actual data set and quite importantly the code you used to call `hmi`. You can click on "edit" below your question to update it with more information/code.

Comment: Updated! Thanks @Qaswed

Comment: I ran your example and get no errors. Is it possible something else in your environment that's causing the error?